# custom space between containers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create custom space between two containers inside a row. As you can see when **image** container ends **another container begins**. Tried to do this with wrapping Row with Padding but no effect.

[image]

Here's my code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Align(
          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
          child: LayoutBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints constraints) {
              return Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
                    child: Stack(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.lightBlue,
                        ),
                        CustomPaint(
                          size: Size.infinite,
                          painter: MyPainter(pointsList: points),
                        ),
                        displayImage(context, widget.imagePath),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.75,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 4,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

And here's the result I've had till now:

[image]

Comment: maybe add a container of a specific width between them with empty content

Comment: @SaraBean but that wont make the containers back to back right?

Comment: my bad, I thought you wanted the space between them but you want them to space flexibly so this might not be the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you can use Flexible:

```
Row(
 children:
   [
     Flexible(
        flex 4,
        fit: FlexFit.tight,
        child: Container(color: Colors.green),),
     Flexible(
        flex 1,
        fit: FlexFit.tight,
        child: Container(color: Colors.white),),
     Flexible(
        flex 2,
        fit: FlexFit.tight,
        child: Container(color: Colors.yellow),),
   ],),
```